# How can I hide or remove the split-pane bar on the right in Mac terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, terminal.app, sidebar

What do I need to do to remove the split pane sidebar on the right from the terminal window?  Never used to have it and now I don't know how to get rid of it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I found out what was triggering it. The split-pane sidebar shows up when you have a non-magic mouse plugged in. So my answer for you could be: use an Apple's Magic Mouse.

However I'll tell you how to get rid of it, this will [change the scroll bar behavior](http://osxdaily.com/2011/08/03/show-scroll-bars-mac-os-x-lion/) to show up only when scrolling:

- Launch System Preferences from the  Apple menu
- Click on General
- Look for 'Show scroll bars' and select the radiobox next to "When scrolling"

Comment: Excellent! That did the trick.

Comment: give this man an money, women, and guns.

Comment: I got this even with a magic mouse after a reboot. Turning the magic mouse off, waiting for disconnect, and turning it back on again caused the bar to clear.

Comment: So Apple think you'll need to split and mirror the terminal if are using a non magic mouse?

Comment: still in 2021, this was helpful, started using a wireless mouse, and these bars appeared on my terminal windows.

Comment: yeah this is pretty annoying.  I actually used to use KVM software to control my mac instead of actually plugging in a mouse to it.

I stopped using the KVM software and plugged in my mouse/keyboard to the macbook for the first time and I kinda regret it (for a few reasons) :laughing:  I still want to see my scrollbars all the time though so this is particularly annoying to me.

Comment: I noticed this in my new mac but could not figure out how to disable it even comparing two mac books side by side. I googled for "split pane button" but no relevant results. So this is called the"split pane bar".

Answer (score 18):

Shift-Command-D or the "Close Split Pane" item in the View menu should do it.

Comment: See also [How do I disable Cmd-D in Terminal?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/254222/60079).